# Can I send Push notifications to those users who have un-installed my android app?

Tags: push-notification

I unity developer, I used "onesignal.com" to send push notification to my active users. Now please guide me is there any way to send messages to those who have un-installed my app ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is too funny! :D Imagine the spam if this could happen.
To answer your question, no its not possible.

Comment: I installed once a Game, I received push notifications, but even after un installing the Game, I was still receiving push notifications. 

I asked it, may be there is way to send the notifications based on android device id.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is no and another thing this is not logical to send push notification after the app is uninstalled.